# Отключить кэширование в wordpress

Tags: wordpress, кэширование

Файл .htaccess

```html
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

# сжатие text, html, javascript, css, xml:
<ifModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml application/xml application/xhtml+xml text/css text/javascript application/javascript application/x-javascript
</ifModule>
 
# кеш браузера
<ifModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
 
#по умолчанию кеш в 5 секунд
ExpiresDefault "access plus 5 seconds"
 
# Включаем кэширование изображений и флэш на месяц
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 4 weeks"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 30 days"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 43829 minutes"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 2592000 seconds"
 
# Включаем кэширование css, javascript и текстовых файлоф на одну неделю
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 10 seconds"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 10 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 10 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 10 seconds"
 
# Включаем кэширование html и htm файлов на один день
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 10 seconds"
 
# Включаем кэширование xml файлов на десять минут
ExpiresByType application/xhtml+xml "access plus 600 seconds"
 
# Нестандартные шрифты сайта 
ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType font/opentype "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 month"
</ifModule>
```

Как сбросить кэш на стороне клиента? Стоит вроде как 10 секунд, а стили не обновляются

Comment: Измените название стилей (версию допишите).

Comment: Ctrl+F5 в браузере

Comment: Переименовал в style.css?ver=4.8.2
Не помогло, или как-то по-другому нужно сделать?

Comment: Если переименование не помогает, то ошибка в другом месте. Не тот файл стилей подключён, например. Потому что переименованный файл - это новый файл для браузера. Каким чудом туда могут попасть старые стили?

Comment: Где и как "переименовал"? 150%  либо не то, либо не там либо не так.

Comment: В папке с темой, лежит файл style.css, его если меняю, стили меняются, но на сайте файл имеет вид style.css?ver=4.8.1. Задача лежит, как сбросить его из кэша? Как  я разобрался то за кэш отвечает файл .htaccess, код выше. Судя по коду кэш стоит на 5 секунд

Comment: А кто писал - переименовал в 4.8.2 - не помогло?

Comment: Так оно версию само добавляет как-то. Когда я сам добавил версию, стили просто отвалились от сайта